# How to Save textboxfor value in SQL using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How to save textboxfor value in SQL in ASP.NET MVC?

View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Total, new { @class = "CateID" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Total, new { @Value = SbTotal, @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Controller:

```
string query3 = "insert into AssesmentModelDetail(Total) values ('"+item.Total+"')"
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Most likely, your view is connected to a **view model** class (which you're not showing) that contains that value in question. Also presumably, the view has a submit button (also not shown) that will post back to a method on the controller (presumably a `POST` method - also not shown) which gets that view model as its parameter. Inside that controller method, you should create a **properly parametrized** query to insert that data into your database. Inshort: you're not **nearly** showing us enough information in order to really help you.....